# Audio not working while playing videos

Tags: audio

Recently my audio stopped working while playing video on the media player. 
If i tried on Potplayer it says `Failed to start playback. It is not possible to play the audio.`

If i tried it on VLC again the audio does work.

Audio doesn't work for online videos too. In all the cases, video does get played but without the audio. Audio for mp3 files works just fine.

OS: Windows 8.1 64 bit

Driver : Realtek High Definition Audio

Comment: @SDsolar Please don't add comments suggesting people take the tour. You have been asked before to stop doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pretty good clues in this description. youtube has a neat feature built in if there isn't a sound card detected on the computer the video won't play.  Check your speaker properties, if

```
Allow applications to take exclusive control of this Device
```

turn it off.  There might be a programming running to trying to take exclusive control.

[image]